# How can I send data like this

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am sending data from php file to javascript with ajax. I want to get javascript variable like this .

```
var members = [
    {memberId : 1, parentId:null, amount:200, otherInfo:"blah"},
    {memberId : 2, parentId:1, amount:300, otherInfo:"blah1"},
    {memberId : 3, parentId:1, amount:400, otherInfo:"blah2"},
    {memberId : 4, parentId:3, amount:500, otherInfo:"blah3"},
    {memberId : 6, parentId:1, amount:600, otherInfo:"blah4"},
    {memberId : 9, parentId:4, amount:700, otherInfo:"blah5"},
    {memberId : 12, parentId:2, amount:800, otherInfo:"blah6"},
    {memberId : 5, parentId:2, amount:900, otherInfo:"blah7"},
    {memberId : 13, parentId:2, amount:0, otherInfo:"blah8"},
    {memberId : 14, parentId:2, amount:800, otherInfo:"blah9"},
    {memberId : 55, parentId:2, amount:250, otherInfo:"blah10"},
    {memberId : 56, parentId:3, amount:10, otherInfo:"blah11"},
    {memberId : 57, parentId:3, amount:990, otherInfo:"blah12"},
    {memberId : 58, parentId:3, amount:400, otherInfo:"blah13"},
    {memberId : 59, parentId:6, amount:123, otherInfo:"blah14"},
    {memberId : 54, parentId:6, amount:321, otherInfo:"blah15"},
    {memberId : 53, parentId:56, amount:10000, otherInfo:"blah7"},
    {memberId : 52, parentId:2, amount:47, otherInfo:"blah17"},
    {memberId : 51, parentId:6, amount:534, otherInfo:"blah18"},
    {memberId : 50, parentId:9, amount:55943, otherInfo:"blah19"},
    {memberId : 22, parentId:9, amount:2, otherInfo:"blah27"},
    {memberId : 33, parentId:12, amount:-10, otherInfo:"blah677"}

];
```

Not like json

```
[{"memberId":"4","parentId":"1","amount":"10","otherInfo":"sds"},{"memberId":"5","parentId":"1","amount":"100","otherInfo":"dsf"},{"memberId":"6","parentId":"4","amount":"1000","otherInfo":"sadsa"}]
```

Comment: You mean the difference in field names? It looks both are refering to different objects.

Comment: On the client side, do a `JSON.parse(response);`

Comment: No... json have qoutes for each value and key

Comment: the first one is also JSON, just not well formatted

Comment: @wroniasty The first one is Javascript, not JSON. By your reasoning, every string can be considered "not-well-formed JSON"

Comment: most JSON parsers will parse the first just as well

Comment: @wroniasty `JSON.parse()` won't, and it is arguably the one you should be most concerned with. jQuery's polyfill also won't parse it in absence of native `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: @MiqdadAli, JSON requires quotes around object keys (and string values).  As for getting numbers for the values instead of numeric strings, you can cast to int (or float) before calling `json_encode()`.

Comment: @MiqdadAli -- Do you mean you want the spaced out version?  Rather than everything on one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written code like this and got it working correct thank you all

```
response = [{"memberId":"4","parentId":"1","amount":"10","otherInfo":"sds"},{"memberId":"5","parentId":"1","amount":"100","otherInfo":"dsf"},{"memberId":"6","parentId":"4","amount":"1000","otherInfo":"sadsa"}];

response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
var members = [
       {memberId : current_id , parentId:null, name:current_name}
    ];
for(var i=0; i<response.length;i++){
   user = {memberId: parseInt(response[i]['memberId']), parentId: parseInt(response[i]['parentId']), name: response[i]['name']};
members.push(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<script>
var members = <?php echo json_encode ($members); ?>;
</script>
```

or this:

```
<script src="source.php"></script>
```

or this:

```
<script>
    jQuery.getJSON ( 'source.php' );
</script>
```

source.php:

```
var members = <? echo json_encode ( $members ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to read the json and then extract the array from it, before this you must create an object with your desired fields so create an instance of it and add to array

```
var items = new Array();
var jsonData = JSON.parse(jsoneString);
for (var i in jsonData) {
    var item = jsonData[i];
    var prop1 = item.memberId;
    //and other items goes here

}
```

i think this is a proper solution for you.

Comment: JSON.parse creates an instance of the object, the `for` loop is pointless